# quotes with php and javascript wrapped in php function

Tags: php, jquery

Using jquery I do this:

```
$(function() {
$('#iButton').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'index.php?option=com_cameras&task=globalmotiondetection&id_hash=<?php echo $id_hash; ?>&global_monitoring='+ (this.checked ? 1 : 0) + '&format=raw'

    });
});
});
```

This works great. But now I'm putting this into a php function (Joomla coding) but can't figure out the quotes:

```
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
$(function() {
$("#iButton").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "index.php?option=com_cameras&task=globalmotiondetection&id_hash='$id_hash'&global_monitoring="+ (this.checked ? 1 : 0) + "&format=raw"
    });
});

});
');
```

This gives me: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on the url line. Not sure how the quotes should look like. I guess I can't just put `$id_hash` in there either (I'm guessing because of the error). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concatenate a  variable into single-quoted string, you can use the concatenate operator `.`:

```
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
$(function() {
$("#iButton").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "index.php?option=com_cameras&task=globalmotiondetection&id_hash=' . $id_hash . '&global_monitoring="+ (this.checked ? 1 : 0) + "&format=raw"
    });
});

});
');
```

Alternatively, you can use a double-quoted string instead, which allows you to interpolate the variable right inside:

```
$doc->addScriptDeclaration("
$(function() {
$('#iButton').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'index.php?option=com_cameras&task=globalmotiondetection&id_hash=$id_hash&global_monitoring='+ (this.checked ? 1 : 0) + '&format=raw'
    });
});

});
");
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it more simple, use Heredoc. see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

```
$str = <<<EOT
$(function() {
    $("#iButton").change(function() {
        $.ajax({
           url: "index.php?option=com_cameras&task=globalmotiondetection&id_hash='$id_hash'&global_monitoring="+ (this.checked ? 1 : 0) + "&format=raw"
        });
    });
});

EOT;
```